# How to make @Ajax.ActionLink not update

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there any way to make `@Ajax.ActionLink()` not update `UpdateTargetId`?
For example, with something like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("All", "Get_Books_By_Id", new { ID = 0 }, 
    new AjaxOptions() { 
        HttpMethod = "GET", 
        UpdateTargetId = "div_records", 
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
        LoadingElementId = "div_load" 
    }
)
```

`Get_Books_By_Id` is returning `PartialView` with data for table in `PartialView`, but I would like to not update `UpdateTargetId` when data (List) count is 0, for example.

Is there any way to send via control something what would tell ajax not to update? Or is there any other way?

Comment: Post your partial view and what's inside the div before the ajax call.

Comment: Already done it by making onsuccess javascript function to update or not on some conditions. Thanks for help

Comment: you've already done what? I asked you to post your partial view, and your main view here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:

1. Remove the update target id and instead use the OnSuccess handler

   ```
   function onSuccess(result){
        var fragment = $(result);
        if(fragment.find("tr").length >= 0)        
            $("div_records").html(fragment)
    }
   ```
2. Change your controller to return a different status code from your action

   ```
   public ActionResult Get_books_by_id()
   {
          var myBooks = _repostiory.GetBooksById();
          if(!myBooks.Any())
               return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

          return PartialView("mybooks", myBooks);
    }
   ```

I've used both methods before, and obviously you will need to tailor the selects and actions to your use case.